# Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V Network performance

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

We are a very small shop looking to switch from VM Server 2.0 to Windows 2012 and HyperV.  I re-purposed a desktop PC to try to the hyper-v software which was a Dell 7000 with 16GB, Intel i5 and WD Black 1tb drive.  At the moment I only have a single Hyper-V setup on the server.   Our applications require access to network files and were much slower in Hyper-V than VM Ware.  I tested this by coping 1gb worth of files with robocopy and recording the mb/sec statistics and I'm noticing the hyper-v guest computer have 1/2 (often less than half) the throughput as the physical server.  I have searched online and found a few articles that mention to disable VMQ and disable any Offload settings.  I have done those and not noticed any different in performance.

This doesn't seem right and not sure what to do.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

the next thing I'd try is a different network adapter. I've seen some Broadcom nics have issues with Hyper-V. Almost anything by Intel should work great.